# setValue in react hook form not working with react-datepicker

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, react-datepicker

While i setting value dynamically to react-datepicker throwing an error "RangeError: Invalid time value"
[image]

This is my datepciker code

```
<Controller
   control={control}
   className="form-control"
   name="from_date"
   render={({ field }) => (
           <DatePicker
                onChange={(e) => field.onChange(e)}
                selected={field.value}
                dateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy"
                minDate={new Date()}
           />
          )}
  {...register("from_date", { required: true })}/>
```

This is how i setting value to datepicker

```
var mydate = moment(date_from_db, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format("DD-MM-YYYY");
setValue('date_field', mydate)
```

Can anyone explain whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Hi! Why have you `Controller` and `register` with the same `name`? Can you provide a codesanbox with your issue, thank you

Answer (score -1):

Try doing

```
<Controller
   control={control}
   className="form-control"
   name="from_date"
   render={({ field }) => (
           <DatePicker
                onChange={(e) => field.onChange(e)}
                selected={field.value}
                dateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy"
                minDate={new Date()}
           />
          )}
  {...register("from_date", { required: true })}/>

var mydate = moment(date_from_db).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
setValue('from_date', mydate)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.